# Huge database table design issue

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

In my DB design I've encountered an issue. My app consists of a workflow on specific kind of media which has 6 stages as follows :

1. Resources
2. Ingest
3. Review
4. VideoRepair
5. Listing
6. backup

Since in all the stages the type of data being added (or updated) to table is the same but only their names change for example in ingest we have following columns

```
CaptureSup_Name, Assign_DateByCaptureSup, AssignedCaptureOp_Name,
LastCapture_Date, LastCaptureOp_Name, LastCapture_Date,
```

and in review we have exactly same columns but only Ingest replaces with Review and almost the same happens for the other columns of table (with one or two columns more or less)and for the purpose of having better performance on select queries So I decided not to assign one table for each stage (tradition normalization) and on the contrary I wrapped them all in one unified table

And now my table has 30 columns and the number of 30 in columns is scaring me because I never designed such a big table. Which of the following scenarios is most suitable for my case considering my database is supposed to support huge amount of data (about 1500 records being added daily) and speed is vital?

1. following the traditional normalization approach and break my big table into 6 or 7 tables each of which have about 5 or 6 columns o that I have to write (n-1) joins to retrieve complete data of cycle
2. keep my current design (one table with 30 columns) and find solution for reducing size of logs because in this case logs would be more massive (because of updates)

Comment: 30 columns and 1500 rows per day - that's *hardly* a "huge" database......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30 fields is not a wide table. SQL Server supports over 1,000 fields per table.

1,500 records per day is not a large volume of inserts. That is only about 500 thousand rows per year. SQL Server can handle billions of rows.

If you are having an issue with logs, then you have several options, such as:

- switching to simple recovery mode;
- periodically backing up the database and truncating the log; and,
- using database checkpoints.

You should break your table up into other tables, if that makes sense in terms of the relational model -- this is likely, because 30 columns in a table would often be combinations of other entities. But your data structure is easily in the realm of what databases readily support. And, it can grow much, much larger with no problems (assuming none of your columns are really humongous).

Comment: if I break it to an other tables for example 7 tables (instead on one) of course it would make more sense in terms of relational databases but if I do so I would have two issues first in order to get data of complete cycle I'd have to write 6 joins which I think my queries in this case would be much slower than my current scenario which only needs one join (two tables) for getting whole cycle data and second query writing would be much more time consuming considering I have a very tight deadline

Comment: @aspHunter . . . What you think is not necessarily correct.  Joins on the primary keys of tables should be very, very fast, and could be faster than accessing an unnormalized table.